# Smarty Paginate Plugin and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: smarty, twitter-bootstrap, smarty3

I try to implement Twitter Bootstrap pagination with Smarty Paginate plugin.

Thats my problem: when I create paginate block, looks like:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
<ul>
    <li>{paginate_prev text="&larr;" class="active"}</li>
    {paginate_middle format="page" prefix="" suffix="" link_prefix="<li>" link_suffix="</li>"}
    <li>{paginate_next text='&rarr;'}</li>
</ul>
```

I have result looks like (active page is two):

```
    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="..." text="&larr;">&larr;</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">1</a></li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li><a href="...">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="..." text="&rarr;">&rarr;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcgUU.png)

Twitter Bootstrap pagination class must have link in active "li" element. How I can insert link into active "li" in smarty paginate?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to fix this in the css than in smarty. Similar issues with other outputs (eg cakephp). Can you cadd classnames to the current & first LI's?

If so, add the css for the link to the active LI,

```
float: left;
padding: 0 14px;
line-height: 34px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-left-width: 0;
margin-left: 0px;
```

and then add border-left-width:1px to the first item.

```
.pagination .previous{
     border-left-width: 1px;
}
```